# Undefined index error for $_POST in signup

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

this is my signup.php code:

```js
<?php
include "connect.php";
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$query = "INSERT INTO user(email,pass)VALUES (:email,:pass)";
$res=$connect->prepare($query);
$res->bindParam(":email",$email);
$res->bindParam(":pass",$pass);
$res->execute();

if($res){
    echo $email;
}else{
    echo "error";
}
```

resault :

[image]

Comment: Your form is using `method="get"`, so you need to use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: Or you should change the form to use `method="post"`, because you don't want passwords to be included in the URL.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!x** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.